# Passing Data from One View to Another view in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Am searching for answers for Passing Data from One View to Another view in MVC but may be i did not find the correct link and posting here.

```
I have Controller A mapping to view A
I have Controller B mapping to view B
```

From View A i need to pass a Textbox value to View B.

One option i see in common is

```
@Url.Action("Index", "B", new { test = testName})
```

But this one will show the data in URL. I don want to do that

But am looking for any alternative approach. Any suggestions ?

Thanks

Comment: Include it in the model for both actions and populate model B in view A's post action?

Comment: I think this approach is not appropriate with MVC Architecture.

Comment: Why don't you want the parameter to appear in the url? This is fairly standard for MVC (and indeed html), if the data is sensitive then it should be hashed or encrypted.

Answer (score 2):

You could use an HTML form that will submit the value of the textbox to the second controller:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("index", "b", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.SomeValue)
    <button type="submit">OK</button>
}
```

Since we are using a POST request the value will be sent in the body of this request and it will not be part of the resulting query string.